# Return SQL data to C# object

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am developing a website using ASP.NET C#. I have an SQL-Server database. I want to be able to retrieve data from the table with my data already in it.

For example, [Here is my Details Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjzxu.jpg). I want to be able to do something like `SELECT SteamName FROM Details WHERE SteamID = @SteamID` and return the value that I get from the query to a C# object.

Here is the C# I have tried:

```
private void ReadSteamDetails()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT SteamID FROM Details WHERE SteamID = @SteamID";
            command.Parameters.Add("@SteamID", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            command.Parameters["@SteamID"].Value = SteamID;

            connection.Open();
            DisplaySQLID = command.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Running this code simply returns `-1`

Comment: Show the c# code that you are trying

Comment: Don't use `ExecuteNonQuery()`, use `ExecuteScalar()`.

Comment: use DataAdapter instead of SqlCommand

Comment: @Amit What do you mean Issue Statement? Error message?

Comment: use any ORM instead of sql commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [`ExecuteNonQuery()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.7.1), that returns an int value indicating the number of rows effected by the SQL statement. It should be used with `insert`, `update` or `delete`, but not with `select` statement.

When executing a `select` statement, you should use either [`ExecuteReader()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.7.1) if you want to iterate the query result using a [`DataReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.7.1), or use a [`DataAdapter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.7.1) to fill a `DataSet` or a `DataTable`, or use [`ExecuteScalar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteScalar) if your query should return 0 or 1 results (and that's the case here).
Also, your code can and should be shorter - for instance, you can specify the select statement and connection object directly in the `SqlCommand` constructor.

Here is how I would write it:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT SteamID FROM Details WHERE SteamID = @SteamID", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@SteamID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = SteamID;
        connection.Open();
        DisplaySQLID = command.ExecuteSalar()?.ToString() ?? "";
    }
}
```

Note that your query might not return any result so the `ExecuteScalar()` will return `null`, hence the use if the null conditional operator ([`?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)) and the null coalescing operator ([`??`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator)).

Answer (score 2):

For that exact query use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: I could have sworn that I tried this... So simple... Thanks for making me feel stupid :P But seriously, Thank You! Just gotta wait for the answer timer

Answer (score -1):

you can use the Entity Framework for that purpose. . .

with the combination of Entity Framework and link u can get your desire result set .

**Entities entities = new Entities(Connection-String);**

**var result = entities.Details.Where(a=>a.SteamID = @SteamID )**